Signal R through KONG and Bearer token showing handshake was cancelled error after negotiate version
I am trying to implement signal R through KONG with .net core.
I am able to get connection Id but the subsequent connections are failing .
Did anyone got signalR working through react, .net core and KONG
negotiate version is working fine but the subsequent requests are failing

You should share your sample code and error messages.
